# When I close a window and then open a different one, the selected tab is recreated by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension that saves/restores your browsers window state - So, I save the state of a given window:

```
     var properties = [ "top", 
                "left",
                "width",
                "height",
                "incognito",
                "focused",
                "type"
              ];
     var json = {};
     var cache = chrome_window_object;

     // copy only the keys we care about:
     _.each(properties,function(key,value) {
            json[key] = cache[key];
        });

     // then copy the URLs of the tabs, if they exist:

     if(cache.tabs) {
         json.url = [];
         _.each(cache.tabs,function(tab) {
            json.url.push(tab.url);
            });
     }

     return json;
```

At some point in the future, I remove all windows:

```
     closeAllWindows: function(done_callback) {
     function got_all(windows) {
     var index = 0;

     // use a closure to only close one window at a time:
     function close_next() {
         if(windows.length <= index) return;

         var window = windows[index++];
         chrome.windows.remove(window,close_next);
     }

     // start closing windows:
     close_next();
     }
     chrome.windows.getAll(got_all);
 }
```

and then I restore the window using:

```
chrome.windows.create(json_from_before);
```

The window that is created has an extra tab in it, whatever was in the window that I just closed...  I am completely floored, and I assume the problem is something that I am doing in the code that I haven't posted (it's a big extension).  I've spent a few hours checking code line by line and making sure I'm not explicitly asking for this tab to be created.  So - has anybody seen anything like this before?

Comment: Have you checked whether the JSON string has an extra tab in it?  The problem is either that you are including an extra tab when serializing the window or that you are creating an extra tab when it isn't described in the JSON.

Comment: @apsillers - That was the first thing I checked - the JSON blob I'm passing to .create has no such tab in it.   It's being added by me/chrome after the window is created.  My main question, I guess, is  there some way I can find out why/if chrome created a tab?